# Authenticate users against Azure Active Directory from PHP web application

Tags: php, azure, amazon-web-services, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have a website in PHP and want to authentificate users against Azure Active Directory. With ldap_connect and bind I have no problems to do this to a local AD-Server in our company.

```
function checkADAccount($username, $password)
{
    $adServer = "myADServer";
    $ldaprdn = 'myDomain' . "\\" . $username;

    $ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);

    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    $bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldaprdn, $password);

    if ($bind) {
        @ldap_close($ldap); // Verbindung schließen
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But my application is hosted at Amazon Web Services (AWS) and is not in the same domain, so I can't use this way.
With ldap_connect and bind this functions to a local AD-Server in our company. But my application is hosted at Amazon Web Services (AWS) and is not in the same domain, so I can't use this way.
I tested [graphapi](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-php-graphapi-web) with the ClientId and key for my company from Azure. So I can read the users-data, but I don't see any possibility to check a user/password combination. I only want to check, if there exists a user with this password, I don't need to read it from there.
So I tried to modify the LDAP-solution from above by changing the parameter of the adServer and of the user

 `$ldaprdn = 'sAMAccountname=' . $username . ',cn=users' . ',dc=myDomain,dc=com';`

But I allwaws get: *"Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server "*. I tried for this multiple versions for the adServer but any delievers a binding.
Do you have any idea where is the error. I suggest with ldap_connect is the wron way, espacially I don't know which server-adress is the right one and how I had to tell the ClientId and key.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Azure AD doesn't support LDAP connection. It provides OAuth2 authentication and authorization. You can refer to [Authentication Scenarios for Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/) for detailed Azure AD scenarios.

For your requirement to authenticate users in your domain, you can leverage this [code sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/php-connect-rest-sample) to implement authentication via Azure AD.

Otherwise, you can follow [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) build your custom code to authenticate your users.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Need to do the same thing but I don't see anything in that code example that actually authenticates the users login against Azure AD?

Comment: @mederomuraliev, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509761/connect-to-azure-active-directory-from-php-web-application

Comment: So this referenced LDAP snippet would be for a more older setup, not a modern Azure AD setup? https://github.com/ssswang/CakeLDAP