# Auth Azure with php

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to make a auth with microsoft azure, I've registered my app in some places like the Azure portal, y the link to register app in easyauth.azurewebsites.net, enven here apps.dev.microsoft.com, and then i copy de App Id in my code, also i'm trying to use the Graph API to auth and to use some Outlook services in a connection to a local app using lampp, and the app is in php.
when I register the app i use the url localhost/app/app.php

here's the code I'm trying with easy auth

```
 <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#theButton").on('click',function(){

        AzureADAuth.getAccessToken()
            .then(function(token){
                alert(token);
            })
            .error(function(err){
                alert("something gone wrong") 
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: What exact issue are you running into? Do you want to connect to Azure Active Directory from PHP web application ? If yes ,please refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509761/connect-to-azure-active-directory-from-php-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an exact question so instead I'll just give you a general answer. To support either Azure AD (work or school accounts) or Microsoft Accounts (outlook, xbox, hotmail) you can register your the app inside the [App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com). Then, you'll need to configure this application by creating an app secret/password and set a redirect URI.

Then you can integrate the app with some OAuth2.0 library. I've [written a small PHP sample using the phpleague OAuth2.0 client](https://github.com/danieldobalian/AADv2-php-app) that you can checkout for this.